# laravel edit data using checkboxes

Tags: php, laravel

I am currently working on a laravel project using multiple table's and pivot table's

Now i want to edit a 'file'
a file exists out of: id, desc_long, desc_short, file(pdf,docx etc.), language_id, roles.
The problem is that a file can have multiple 'roles'. so using a pivot table i can now succesfully create a file with multiple roles. there are only 4 roles and this will not be updated at all! : 'admin', 'distributeur', 'dealer', 'partner'

If i press on edit a file it **should** check the checkboxes with the roles as in the database. but it only checks the first checkbox where the value is the same:
as you can see on the image, only 'distributeur' is checked. but dealer also should be checked since the pivot table contains the 'dealer' ID aswell. [image]

the edit.blade:

```
                <label>{{('Role')}}</label>
                @foreach($allroles as $rol)
                <label><input type="checkbox" value="{{$rol->id}}" @if($file_role->role_id == $rol->id) checked=checked @endif>{{$rol->name}}</label>
                @endforeach
            </div>
```

the controller:

```
 public function edit($id, Request $request, )
    {
        $files = File::all();
        $fileEdit = File::find($id);
        $roles = Role::all();
        $allroles = Role::all();
        $file_role = File_Role::where('file_id', '=', $id)->first();
        $file_subfolder = File_Subfolder::all();
       // dd($file_role);
        return view('admin.file.index', compact('files', 'fileEdit', 'roles', 'allroles' ,'file_role', 'file_subfolder'));
    }
```

as you can see on the line

```
     $file_role = File_Role::where('file_id', '=', $id)->first();
```

i have to use ->first();. if i use ->get(); i get this error: Property [role_id] does not exist on this collection instance.

if i need to add extra information i will gladly do so!

Comment: Well yeah, if you use `->get()` you get multiple `File_Role`, and `$file_role->role_id` doesn't know **which instance of `File_Role` you're trying to get `role_id` from**; you would need to loop it, like `foreach($file_roles as $file_role)`, then `$file_role->role_id` would be valid, or use `->first()` as your doing. Also, your `<input type="checkbox">` is missing a `name="..."` attribute, so nothing will be sent to the backend when you submit this form.

Comment: <label>{{('Role')}}</label>
                foreach($allroles as $rol)
                foreach($file_role as $file_roles)
                <label><input name="roles" type="checkbox" value="{{$rol->id}}" if($file_role->role_id == $rol->id) checked=checked endif>{{$rol->name}}</label>
                endforeach
                endforeach
still gives he same error:  Property [role_id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: You called `foreach($file_role as $file_roles)`, then `$file_role->role_id`... So yes, it would. The issue here is not an extra `foreach()`, you're likely looking for something like `{{ $file_roles->includes($role->id) ? 'checked' : '' }}` or similar. But you need to figure out the difference between `$file_roles`, a Collection, via `->get()`, and `$file_role`, a `FileRole` instance, via `->first()`; you're missing understanding of that crucial part.